# Regex to validate salary format with comma AND dot

Tags: regex

I need your help in improving the code I have here as the code that I have is missing the validation for the commas. The code needs to have both the comma and the dot on it please.

Current Regex:

```
((\d){1,3})+([,][\d]{3})*(\.\d+)
```

The request to have 2 decimal points in it is working but it's also accepting the value even if there are no commas in it.

Accepted values would be:
`1,000,000.00`
`100,000.00`
`100,000.00`
`10,000.00`
`10.00`
`1.00`

Not accepted:
`1000`
`1000.00` and so on

Comment: Please add info in which technology you want to do this. There are a little differences between implementations. Paste also example code, to see a context.

Comment: What language are you trying to use? Regex seems to change a little from one programming language to another.

Comment: Please try [**`^(?:\d{1,2}|(?=.*?,.*)[\d,]+)(?:\.\d+)?$`**](https://regex101.com/r/Xj5tlV/1)If you want digits only two decimal places use `(?:\.\d{1,2})` at last.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, you just didn't anchor your regex, so it was passing for partial matches as well. I cleaned it up for you and anchored it, you can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/aTN6wm/1):

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d+$
```